# how to load a static library(libtest.a) in MainActivity.java in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I have got a static library libtest.a (src\main\obj\local\armeabi) and I want to test if its working or not. So now how to load a static library(libtest.a) in MainActivity.java in (android studio(1.1.0),gradle-2.2.1,ndk-crystaXndk from https://www.crystax.net/en/download) so its functionality of returning a  string gets printed in the VirtualDevice(AVD)? Since I had used System.Loadlibrary(test) which automatically adds the suffix .so now I am getting an error saying libtest.so not found. There is only libtest.a file how to refer in the .java file?

```
--------- beginning of crash
06-26 13:17:12.284    1948-1948/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 1948
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "liblibtest.so"
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
            at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:13)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)}



 Android.mk

        LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
        include $(CLEAR_VARS)
        LOCAL_MODULE    := test
        LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
        LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libtest
        include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY) //to build this libtest.a and use the same

        include $(CLEAR_VARS)
        LOCAL_MODULE    := super
        LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtest.a
        include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY

    Application.mk

        APP_CFLAGS += -fexceptions
        APP_STL := gnustl_static
        APP_STL := stlport_static


  test.cpp

//#include "test.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
/*char* getString12();
char* Java_com_danfoss_myapplication_Application_getString12()
{   char x[80]="Hello World!!!";
    char *s1 = new char [sizeof(x)];
     strcpy(s1,x);
     return s1;
}*/
extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_danfoss_myapplication_MainActivity_getString12(JNIEnv *env,
                                                     jobject obj)
//    {   char sk[30]="hello-world!!!";
//        const char *v = (const char *)sk;
         jstring x="hellllooooo!!!!";
//        return (*v)->NewStringUTF(env,"Hello from C++ JNI !");
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.loadLibrary(libtest)` not only appends `.so`on Android, it also prepends `lib`. Therefore it is searching for `liblibtest.so`.

Comment: thanks for the info! I know that it searches for libtest.so I wanted to know some mechanism where the ndk-build automatically searches for libtest.a file.

Comment: No, it is not searching for `libtest.so` but for `liblibtest.so` (two times lib at the beginning). If you want to use libtest.so change the name of your library to "test".

Comment: Thank you now I am able to get the libtest.so library but I am not able to use the C++-function(where it just returns a string) in my MainActivity.java. I get the error Unfortunately, Application got terminated in the android emulator. I can added my C++ code if you want?

Comment: I have tried executing by commenting either of the test.cpp method.. and both dont work.

Comment: Create a new question with your JNI code. Writing correct JNI code has few pitfalls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can load a static library from Java file.

Hoewer replace `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)` by `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` and delete the end of your Android.mk. That way you will build a shared library `.so` that you will be able to load from java file

Comment: I am not using the android ndk but crystaX ndk, so I wanted to know if that supports loading static library?

Comment: The compilation is not the same thing that loading the library at runtime. Your error is because android can only load shared library `.so` and you tried to load a static lobrary `.a`

Comment: Thanks, I got it! But is there by any chance some other possible way of loading the static library,is so do let me know would really be helpful?